# getting dateTime from window explorer in .net side

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get the Datetime from window explorer in my .net code. I tried to do it like this, but did not get the correct date time.

```
 Dim test As DateTime = GetExplorerDateTime(tempFile)

Private Function GetExplorerDateTime(Filename As FileInfo) As DateTime
    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim localOffSet As TimeSpan = now - now.ToUniversalTime()
    Return File.GetLastAccessTimeUtc(filename.Name) + localOffSet
End Function
```

My file in window explorer looks like this:

```
Name         Date modified             Type           Size
TestFile      4/16/2015 08:08 PM       Text Document   3 KB
```

I am trying to get 4/16/2015  08:08 PM in my .net code side. I tried to Google it, but none of the code seems to be getting the correct date time from the window explorer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to get the date modified value of the file you created, correct?

Comment: What is the problem ? `FileInfo.LastAccessTime`. Why do you need calc if you have all you need already built -in?

Comment: What vital role does Explorer play in this?  Explorer does not create or store file data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc
```

or
    `File.GetLastWriteTime`

You are currently getting the date it was *accessed* not the date it was *modified*.

Comment: I keep getting the current date and time so I am getting 3/1/2016 10:20:11. I tried both GetLastwriteTimeUtc and GetLastWriteTime. I tried FileInfo.GetLastWriteTimeUtc